# How does one generally control action based on configuration using CMake?

Tags: cmake

CMake has CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE, which allows customization for single target generators. But this is completely worthless for multiple target generators, as CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is ignored.

(Consider for the sake of example that I want to have a target (such as a lengthy Doxygen build) that I only want to build in release mode for Visual Studio generators and for nmake generators.)

Comment: That's why I always make a separate cmake target for my doxygen generation that is not part of the "ALL" cmake target; then I build the doxygen target manually at release time.  Yours is a good question.

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK, CMake isn't ignoring `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` for multiple target generators, at least for Visual Studio projects. So, if you do something like this:

```
if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Release")
...
endif()
```

it would work only when "Release" is selected in IDE.

Comment: I don't think this will work.  Your "if" statement is executed early, at cmake configuration time.  The OPs selection of "Release" in the Visual Studio IDE takes place later, at build time.

Comment: That's why i've put "AFAIK". The VS generator should put code generated from that if() into Release section of .vsproj. But i'm not sure.

Comment: I can confirm that this is in fact being ignored. (Specifically, CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is the empty string when building for visual studio)